# What is the shortest way to set font color in HTML?

Tags: html, css, colors

The typical sort way is `style="color:#A00;"` however, I'm wanting to set a different color in each cell of a large table, and it's getting kind of bulky and causing my page's download size to increase from all these style tags just to change the font color.

What I ***wish*** is to simply say `<red>Hi, I'm red colored!</red>`, but obviously that doesn't work. But I'm guessing there is nothing except this long, drawn-out statement to set the color?

Comment: Why not use classes instead?

Comment: You can embed a piece of JavaScript on the page and have it set the colours for you. You could generate the hex values dynamically. This way you'd save some bandwidth at the cost of executing some client-side code.

Comment: Using a proper stylesheet would be better. If there is some logic to the "different colour in each cell" you might be able to express that using CSS selectors.

Comment: Add css classes for your colors and use them from javascript

Comment: Vector: Because then I have to also have a class for every color, on top of still having to put in class="???" in the very least..

Comment: If the download size is worrying you, then just set up your server to support HTTP gzip encoding. Repeated chunks of text compress very well.

Answer (score 1):

Into CSS:

```
.red {
    color: red;
}

red {
    color: red;
}
```

Into HTML:

```
<red>Im red!</red>
<span class="red">Im red too!</span>
```

Comment: @Quentin It is valid HTML.

Comment: @Quentin try it and tell me

Comment: @nicael — No, it is not

Comment: @lante — Browsers future proofing themselves against possible additions to the HTML standard does not mean that any element you care to invent becomes part of the HTML standard.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a different color per cell and really don't want tags, I'd suggest building a JavaScript snippet to generate the colors and apply them. You could figure out what the right RGB colors are and increase their integers each cell.

Knowing more about your use case might help though.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a two different colors for each row very easily. If that's what your looking for, then there are many online HTML, CSS table generator sites. [This](http://www.csstablegenerator.com/) is one that I've found Good.